# Why does die execute even if the macro is executed successfully

Tags: perl, die

I was trying to execute a macro using perl and i came across the following problem, if the code is

`$myObject->{DoCmd}->RunMacro("Delete") or die "Could not run macro\n";`

The program would successfully execute including the macro and die saying `Could not run macro` Why is die acting weird though the execution is successful ? Is there any other method to check if the macro is executed or not ?

Comment: What is returned by `$myObject->{DoCmd}->RunMacro("Delete")`? If it's `0` on success, then I think it would make sense that the program will die. (`0 or die`)

Comment: @Matt I tried `$a=$myObject->{DoCmd}->RunMacro("Delete");` and printed `$a` but i get a blank line( I mean no value)

Comment: @Programmer Perl will treat a blank line as a false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that what is being returned by `$myObject->{DoCmd}->RunMacro("Delete")` evaluates to false in Perl.

When this code is run,

```
$myObject->{DoCmd}->RunMacro("Delete") or die "Could not run macro\n";
```

Perl will first run the code on the left side of the `or`. If it evaluates to false, then it will evaluate the code on the right (which makes the program die).

Here is a quote from perldoc about [falsehood](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood) in Perl :

> The number 0, the strings '0' and "" , the empty list () , and undef
>   are all false in a boolean context. All other values are true.
>   Negation of a true value by ! or not returns a special false value.
>   When evaluated as a string it is treated as "" , but as a number, it
>   is treated as 0. Most Perl operators that return true or false behave
>   this way.

Comment: If 0 means "OK" and other means error, the you can rewrite the code as: `$myObject->{DoCmd}->RunMacro("Delete")==0 or die "Could not run macro\n";`